# UIToolbar UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitoolbar

I am trying to add a toolbar onto a UIWebView.  I have a tableview that when a row is selected, it pushes a UIWebView, in that web view I want a toolbar where I can add forward and back buttons. I am working through a book on iOS programming and this is how they've asked for the exercise be done.  So far I have been unable to get the toolbar to actually show up in the WebView so my question is what am I doing wrong in getting the toolbar to display? Here is my code in my UIWebViewController.m

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.view = webView;

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 360,44);

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: frame];


UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(goBack)];

NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:back, nil];

[toolBar setItems:items animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:toolBar];
```

When I run this, the toolbar is not displayed.  I've tried a lot of different configurations with the actual CGRect frame positioning, and that doesn't.  What is confusing me more, is if I take this same code (with some modifications to the toolbar view and drop it in the app delegate in a test project, the toolbar is displayed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44)];

toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
UIBarButtonItem *forward = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward target:self action:@selector(goForward)];

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[items addObject:space];
[items addObject:back];
[items addObject:forward];

[toolBar setItems:items animated:YES];


[self.window addSubview:toolBar];

return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok in terms of creating the UIToolbar, but I think self.view might not exists in the time you create it or self.window is still nil in that moment.

Make sure you call your code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` method and both `self.view` and `self.window` exists at that point.

=== EDIT ===

I think another problem is you are adding it as subview of UIWebView.
Try adding UIWebView as subview for your view.

```
[self.view addSubview:webView]
```

The way you do it seems wrong if you load stuff from nib, you should not overwrite `view` this way.

Comment: I've tried the same code in loadView and I still don't see the toolbar, and the first code snippet above where I instantiate the toolbar was in the loadView method. The web view is being called from the tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath with the following code
    `[self.navigationController pushViewController: self.webViewController
                                         animated: YES].`   So the WebView does have a navigation controller, but given that my frame is 0,0,360,44.  Shouldn't the toolbar reside at the bottom of the window?

Comment: if I add my code into the viewWillAppear method this works. I don't get why it doesn't work if I have it in viewDidLoad. Apples documentation says that the viewDidLoad method is called for views created programmatically or a nib.I also added an NSLog to my viewDidLoad method and it was printed out to the console proving it was called, but if the code to add the toolbar is in that method it will not display.I had to change the code for the toolbar frame slightly to `CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height -44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);` instead of having the origin at 0,0

Comment: I gave that a try, but if i try to do [self.view addSubview:webView], it throws an crashes and throws an exception of "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'".  As a note though nothing is being loaded from a nib, everything has been created programatically.  Thanks for the help here, for now i'll leave my code in viewWillAppear even though it seems it should work in viewDidLoad as well.

Comment: If you could share the code on GIT so I can run it and see that is crashing, that's gonna be so much easier. But the error you pasted is probably coming due to one mistake you've done: you should remove "self.view = webView;" and replace that with "[self.view addSubview:webView]" - you probably left "self.view = webview"